# Get the Month with year including one character in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, backend

I'm trying to get the months list with year like [
"2019M10",
"2019M11",
"2019M12",
"2020M01",
"2020M02",
"2020M03",
"2020M04",
"2020M05",
"2020M06",
"2020M07",
"2020M08",
"2020M09",
"2020M10",
"2020M11",
"2020M12",
"2021M01",
"2021M02",
"2021M03",
"2021M04",
"2021M05"
]
Following Code Sample I'm using

```
import datetime
import json
from_year = 2018
last_year = datetime.datetime.now().year
print(last_year)
year_list = list(range(from_year, last_year))
new_month = []
for all_year in year_list:
    all_months = [str(all_year)+'M'+str(i) for i in list(range(1,13))]
    all_months.extend(all_months)
print(all_months )
months = json.dumps(all_months)
print(months)
```

I'm not getting the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Timestamp.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.to_period.html) for actual year and month, create `PeriodIndex` by [`period_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.period_range.html) and then convert values to format `YYYYMmm` by [`PeriodIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.strftime.html):

```
from_year = 2018
last_year = pd.to_datetime('now').to_period('m')
print(last_year)
2021-07

months = pd.period_range(from_year, last_year, freq='M').strftime('%YM%m').tolist()
print (months)
['2018M01', '2018M02', '2018M03', '2018M04', '2018M05', '2018M06', '2018M07', '2018M08',
 '2018M09', '2018M10', '2018M11', '2018M12', '2019M01', '2019M02', '2019M03', '2019M04',
 '2019M05', '2019M06', '2019M07', '2019M08', '2019M09', '2019M10', '2019M11', '2019M12', 
 '2020M01', '2020M02', '2020M03', '2020M04', '2020M05', '2020M06', '2020M07', '2020M08', 
 '2020M09', '2020M10', '2020M11', '2020M12', '2021M01', '2021M02', '2021M03', '2021M04', 
 '2021M05', '2021M06', '2021M07']
```

If need all months add next year and then slice last value of `months`:

```
from_year = 2018
last_year = pd.to_datetime('now').year + 1
print(last_year)
2022

months = pd.period_range(from_year, last_year, freq='M')[:-1].strftime('%YM%m').tolist()
print (months)
['2018M01', '2018M02', '2018M03', '2018M04', '2018M05', '2018M06', '2018M07', '2018M08', 
 '2018M09', '2018M10', '2018M11', '2018M12', '2019M01', '2019M02', '2019M03', '2019M04',
 '2019M05', '2019M06', '2019M07', '2019M08', '2019M09', '2019M10', '2019M11', '2019M12',
 '2020M01', '2020M02', '2020M03', '2020M04', '2020M05', '2020M06', '2020M07', '2020M08', 
 '2020M09', '2020M10', '2020M11', '2020M12', '2021M01', '2021M02', '2021M03', '2021M04', 
 '2021M05', '2021M06', '2021M07', '2021M08', '2021M09', '2021M10', '2021M11', '2021M12']
```

Your solution with nested list comprehension with flatten:

```
from_year = 2018
last_year = datetime.datetime.now().year
print(last_year)
2021

year_list = list(range(from_year, last_year))

months = [f'{all_year}M{i:02}' for all_year in year_list for i in list(range(1,13))]
print (months)

['2018M01', '2018M02', '2018M03', '2018M04', '2018M05', '2018M06', '2018M07', '2018M08',
 '2018M09', '2018M10', '2018M11', '2018M12', '2019M01', '2019M02', '2019M03', '2019M04', 
 '2019M05', '2019M06', '2019M07', '2019M08', '2019M09', '2019M10', '2019M11', '2019M12', 
 '2020M01', '2020M02', '2020M03', '2020M04', '2020M05', '2020M06', '2020M07', '2020M08', 
 '2020M09', '2020M10', '2020M11', '2020M12', '2021M01', '2021M02', '2021M03', '2021M04',
 '2021M05', '2021M06', '2021M07', '2021M08', '2021M09', '2021M10', '2021M11', '2021M12']
```

Comment: One more thing what If I want 2 months before from current month. like till 2021M05

Comment: @Suchi - It is really simple, use `pd.to_datetime('now').to_period('m') - 2` for 2 months before

Answer (score 0):

you are creating a `new list`  every time you loop and `extending` it .So the last data is getting wiped off and filled with the latest data and you are extending it .So the data is appearing twice.

The solution given by @jezarel is most efficient, but then you can make these modification

```
import datetime
import json
from_year = 2018
last_year = datetime.datetime.now().year
print(last_year)
year_list = list(range(from_year, last_year))
print(year_list)
new_month = []
all_months=[]
for all_year in year_list:
    new_all_months = [str(all_year)+'M'+str(i) for i in list(range(1,13))]
    all_months.extend(new_all_months)
```

Comment: This solution also gives the same result I tried with append also but it didn't work